# preg_match(): Compilation failed: UTF-8 error: byte 2 top bits not 0x80 at offset 2

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

Working on a laravel project I recieved When running a route with this code I didn't write:

```
if(preg_match('/([ΓΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚ])|ΣΤ|fu|ΚΑ|ΚΒ\w+/u', $char)){
   return true;
}
return false;
```

For exapmple whe you give the Γ character you will get the error

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: UTF-8 error: byte 2 top bits not 0x80 at offset 2
```

on php 8.1.9 and working on laravel. the same code works fine from tinker even when passing non english characters. What is the problem

[image]

Comment: _"even when passing non english characters"_ - are you referring to the content of $char here? The error is not about that, it is about the pattern - which fails to compile. The error is not reproducible here either, https://3v4l.org/FBuDm - did you _save_ your PHP script correctly in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Please post the string that you have an issue with.

Comment: What's your text editor? Some of them show in the status bar the encoding being used.

Comment: @CBroe Yes I was referring to the $char.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  take any character that is supposed to match the regex. I updated the question

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález VSCode

Comment: Can you please look at the status bar and check the encoding?

Comment: @CBroe i dont understand what you mean by saving it in the utf8 encoding. I use vscode and I get the laravel output as shown in the image. I updated the question

Comment: So, the code returns false, see https://3v4l.org/HbE5O (Output for 8.0.1 - 8.0.28, 8.1.0 - 8.1.16, 8.2.0 - 8.2.3). Just make sure you save your files in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález "Windows 1253" you mean that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried doing the same in tinker and it works but on laravel it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u` flag in your expression means `UTF-8`. You are using `Windows 1253`, which is not UTF-8.

The best fix is to switch to UTF-8. Click on "Windows 1253", select "Save with encoding" and pick "UTF-8". Laravel and any contemporary web application are designed around UTF-8.

Comment: Mate, you just solved this! :)